# How to get a part of response using jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Consider there is a page with 10 buttons that every ones do a different work.How I can call server-side click event of each one and get response for just that button using jQuery Ajax?
I don't want declare a *static* method for my code.thanks

**EDIT1 :**Consder this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MsAjax.aspx",
    method: "getTime",
    data: { date_in: new Date() },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#div").html(String(data));
    }
});
```

In normal way we code like top code ,but I want click on buttons cause execute it's server side event code but using ajax and page not postback,and get response of it

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"  OnClientClick="nima();"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="nima2();"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Button" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and code behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "11111111";
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = "22222222";
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox3.Text = "3333333";
    }
```

Comment: Could you re-word this to clarify? Or add more details?

Comment: What do you meen by "get response for just that button"? and by "top code"?

Answer (score 0):

define every button with same class and different ids.

```
ex: <input type="button" class="cls_button" id="work1"/>
<input type="button" class="cls_button" id="work2"/>
```

now you can write a jquery ajax script like this

```
$('.cls_button').click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "work="+id,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( msg );
   }

});
});
```

now you can write a switch expression in some.php page to define different works.

**Update:**

you can use same command for "OnCommand" and different "Button id" ex:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" Text="Sort Ascending" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Ascending" OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" runat="server"/> 
<asp:Button id="Button2" Text="Sort Descending" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Descending" OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Sorry I want call Asp.net buttons event code Not PHP.I think php has different way for doing this

Comment: you can use same command for "OnCommand" and different "Button id"


ex:      <asp:Button id="Button1"
           Text="Sort Ascending"
           CommandName="Sort"
           CommandArgument="Ascending"
           OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
           runat="server"/>


 <asp:Button id="Button2"
           Text="Sort Descending"
           CommandName="Sort"
           CommandArgument="Descending"
           OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
           runat="server"/>

Comment: I just for example set text for a textbox.I have not CommandArgument or CommandName